# Web App manifest: `related_applications` and enabled CORP does not load image on Android

Tags: android, google-play, manifest, w3c, cross-origin-resource-policy

Web app manifest with `related_applications` and enabled CORS, CORP, COEP (which are required for our web app) throws an error

Web app manifest

```
...
"related_applications": [
  {
    "platform": "play",
    "url": "xyz",
    "id": "xyz"
  },
],
"prefer_related_applications": true,
...
```

Response headers from our server:

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: "same-origin"
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: "require-corp"
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: "cross-origin"
```

CSP includes:

```
...
img-src 'self' https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com
...
```

Adding `https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com` to CSP we have mitigated CSP error in our reporting dashboard for CSP (uriports.com).

But another error occurred:

```
Type: corp
Error: This is a Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy violation. The loaded resource is cross-origin, but that was not allowed by the CORP policy in the header.
Destination: image
Blocked Url: https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/xyz
```

When I manually change `src` of the image in production, in the browser console an error appears:

`GET https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/xyz net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 400 (Bad Request)`

On the other hand, if I add `<img src="..." crossorigin />` everything works without an issue.

I am not able to set `crossorigin` to image or correct header to response, which is automatically injected by Google on Android.

Article about installation prompt: https://web.dev/learn/pwa/installation-prompt

What is the best way to show Installation prompt for users if I do not want to get rid of COOP, CORP...?